# Create view of columns only if key matches key in other table's column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE PAR (
    ID          varchar(10) not null,
    Name                varchar(20) not null,
    State               varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (ID)
);




INSERT INTO PAR (ID, Name, State)
VALUES
('A000','Susan','New York'),
('B123','Bob','Texas'),
('C456','Tony','Washington'),
('D789','Adam','California');


CREATE TABLE THE_GROUP (
    GroupID         varchar(25) not null,
    Person1         varchar(15) not null,
    Person2         varchar(15) not null,
    Person3         varchar(15),
    Person4         varchar(15),
    primary key (GroupID)
    );


INSERT INTO THE_GROUP (GroupID, Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4)
VALUES
('G234','A000','B666','C777'),
('G456','B123','D898','E632'),
('G789','C456', null, null),
('G444','D789','O123', null);
```

I am trying to create a view that contains Name and state from PAR table  only if the ID matches the value in the 4 Person columns(Person1, Person2, Person3, Person 4)

I've written my query so it looks like this. I do not get an error however the view is just a

```
View    Create View     character_set_client    collation_connection
MY_VIEW     CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`u_904019144`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `MY_VIEW` AS select `P`.`Name` AS `Name`,`P`.`State` AS `State` from (`PAR` `P` join `THE_GROUP` `G`) where ((`G`.`Person1` = `P`.`ID`) or (`G`.`Person2` = `P`.`ID`) or (`G`.`Person3` = `P`.`ID`) or (`G`.`Person4` = `P`.`ID`))   utf8mb4     utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The query I am trying to do is

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS
SELECT P.Name, P.State
FROM PAR AS P, THE_GROUP AS G
WHERE G.Person1 = P.ID OR G.Person2 = P.ID OR G.Person3 = P.ID OR G.Person4 = P.ID

SHOW CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW
```

Comment: *INSERT INTO THE_GROUP* -> Columns amount does not match values amount.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cef152402399a1a4d0f2922a6659c007 But I recommend https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d285bad6b8bf16f028f66a070b0a9fe

Comment: The design of `THE GROUP` table is not a really good. One question, each group will only have 4 person? Can be less than 4 but not more than 4?

Comment: yes it can be less than 4 but not much than 4 persons

Comment: Did you try the code you've posted? It throws an error on the last statement, where you insert 4 values, but specified 5 columns (though, the number of values also vary in different tuples)

Comment: _"yes it can be less than 4 but not much than 4 persons"_ .. maybe that's still acceptable but let's say if your `THE GROUP` table is storing combination of `GroupID`+`Person` by rows, then this part `WHERE G.Person1 = P.ID OR G.Person2 = P.ID OR G.Person3 = P.ID OR G.Person4 = P.ID` will only need to be written `WHERE G.Person = P.ID`. And that's just one of the trouble you'll save yourself from.

Comment: I am getting a 1054 Error code Unknown Column G.Person in where clause

Comment: Well, yes @Morello. On your current table there's no column `G.Person`. I was making an example if your table only stores one `G.Person` column. See this fiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab14ec7fe3deb126ab874d938866acbd